# GStreamer: Noise reduction perhaps by using the pulssink monitor sources

Tags: gstreamer, noise-reduction, pulseaudio

Before I go off on a programming quest I thought I'd ask for guidance that google isn't giving me.

I currently have a gstreamer pipeline that receives sound from a *filesrc*, a *pulsesrc* or *udpsrc* and plays it to a *pulsesink*.  When I use the microphone I get a lot of what I believe is system noise and wondered about doing some kind of noise reduction.  The *udpsrc* and microphone produce a LOT of white (pink?) noise   The *filesrc* sounds great.

So, is there a well know gstreamer noise reduction technique?

One idea I had was to tie the monitor source tied to the *pulsesink* as an input to some sort of sound inverter and play that back on top or the original sound and acheive noise cancellation.

Gstreamer 0.10.36, Xubuntu 12.04.  Proprietary sound system based on a Realtec chipset.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry udpsrc won't produce noise. Maybe the microphone on the other side does.

There are several ways to attack noise. An easy way is to have a nose gate after pulsesrc. This will monitor the recorded signal and mute it if it is below a certain threadhold. This can sounds weird when used for Voip and a technique used there is to combine a comfortnoise generator with the noise gate (voice activity detection).

Other approaches are adaptive noise filtering, either based on a noiseprint or as multiband noise gates.

Comment: Could you point me to a noise gate implementation (example code)?

Comment: Sigh, It's GPL.  No can do.

Comment: C'mon, that was the first hit from googling for hit. Besides the algorithm is quite simple. Maybe look it up on wikipedia and write it yourself then.